# TaskGraph.useFilter alternates for kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Im looking for an alternative to this line of code from gradle and im looking for its counter part in kotlin dsl can anyone shed some light on this as it is blocking builds for me and am at a loss as the usefilter is not available in kotlin dsl

```
gradle.taskGraph.useFilter {
    if (task.name.contains("GoogleServices") && (task.name.contains("Perf") || task.name.contains("Demo") || task.name.contains("Dev") || task.name.contains("Debug"))) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`useFilter`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v5.6.0/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/execution/taskgraph/TaskExecutionGraphInternal.java#L31) is a method declared in a non-public interface `TaskExecutionGraphInternal` which is subtype of the public `TaskExecutionGraph` and is implemented by the actual task graph implementation class.

The call to `useFilter` works in Groovy because of dynamic dispatch: it searches among the all methods of the actual class in run time, thus allowing to call even those methods that are not available through the public API.

In Kotlin, you have to cast the task graph to that interface explicitly to be able to call this method statically:

```
(gradle.taskGraph as org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.TaskExecutionGraphInternal)
    .useFilter { it.name.contains("GoogleServices") && ... }
```

Note that using non public Gradle API makes your build fragile and sensitive to upgrading the version of Gradle.